# Mimic NTFS "Modify" Permissions on an ext3 acl enabled filesystem in linux?

Tags: ntfs, ext3, access-control-list

I am migrating our file share from Windows Server to Samba on Linux, and the only hurdle I have at the moment is the acl's.

Currently we have a number of directories that use the "Modify" permission on NTFS, so users can write to a directory, but once the file is written it cannot be modified.

On Linux, I had the idea that I would set an ACL for the directory to have read/write access, but have a default ACL associated with read only access. Is this possible? I'm not quite sure how to set a default ACL that differs from the parent directory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out myself :-) Assigning a default acl doesn't apply it to the parent directory, so works perfectly!